# $L_1= (1$ { $0, 1$ }$^∗) \cup ${ $0x | x \in L$} is NP- complete

Tags: np-complete, reductions, np

If L is NP-complete then how can I prove that $L_1$:

$L_1= (1$ { $0, 1$ }$^∗) \cup ${ $0x | x \in L$}

is also NP- complete.

My thoughts: A reduction from (for example) SAT to L can be converted to a reduction to { $0x | x \in L$} by adding a 0 to the output.

Answer (score 0):

There is a somewhat trivial reduction from $L$ to $L_1$…

Consider $x\in \Sigma^*$. Then $x\in L \Leftrightarrow 0x\in L_1$. Clearly this reduction is polynomial.

I am sure that you can prove that $L_1\in \mathsf{NP}$.

Comment: So the reduction to $L_1$ is the same as to { $0x | x \in L$}?

Comment: Well, yes, it would be the same.